# Display:none issue with media query

Tags: css, ipad, email, outlook, media

Below is the HTML email template code which we test on different email clients like Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook, Rediffmail, iPhone, iPad.

In this we have two table blocks, we are trying to show the web part on web browsers and mobile part on iPhone and iPad.

But using this code on browser Gmail showing both blocks, Yahoo and Outlook showing mobile and iPhone and iPad showing mobile block.

`@media` does not work properly.

Please suggest me what should I do for the solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Weekly</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #web{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #mobile{
        display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
      @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
        #web{
            display: none;
        }
        #mobile{
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="web">
        <tr>
            <td>
                aditya on web
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="mobile">
        <tr>
            <td>
                aditya on mobile
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

<sup>Sources: https://github.com/Mange/roadie/issues/77</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't support media queries. It doesn't support the `<style>` tag at all, which is why we always inline our css when designing html email.